# How do I query Table A, joining fields from B *and* fields from C only referenced in B?

Tags: sqlite, join

I have this sqlite database:

[image: database:]

And I need to get the set from AssignmentMetric for a certain Athlete_id AND for Assignments which include a skill with Value X.

I've looked all over JOIN, LEFT JOIN but cannot find any examples that seems to match exactly this. I can query to get Assignment metrics for a particular Athlete ID And Assignment ID, but I am trying to narrow the Assignments to ones that are for a specific skill "of X value". How do I "reach through" the Assignment table to grab the value from the Skill table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM
AssignmentMetric
INNER JOIN  Assignment
 ON AssignmentMetric.Assignment_id = 
Assignment.Assignment_id
INNER JOIN
Skill
ON Skill.Skill_id = Assignment.Skill_id
WHERE ...
```

In the WHERE you can refer to the colums of the tables using the tablename.columnname notation.